# How to Solve org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, javabeans

> I am working on the project from a youtube tutorial and get stuck at this Exception.How to Solve org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException?

I am working on the project from a youtube tutorial and get stuck at this Exception. I have seen similar problems here on Stack Overflow but there is an incorrect import problem. I have Checked my Import and there is no problem. I tried to move this file to root and again I caught the same error. I have Tried finding solutions on youtube and On the web also But I didn't get it Anyware. Please help me find out the solution.

Source : https://github.com/DnyaneshwarKolhe/Bookstore.git

```
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
            at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
            at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        2021-02-08 09:47:56.074  INFO 10824 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
        2021-02-08 09:47:56.075  INFO 10824 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
        2021-02-08 09:47:56.094  INFO 10824 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
        2021-02-08 09:47:56.098  INFO 10824 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
        2021-02-08 09:47:56.112  INFO 10824 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
        
        Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
        2021-02-08 09:47:56.250 ERROR 10824 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
        
        ***************************
        APPLICATION FAILED TO START
        ***************************

        Description:
        
        Field userSecurityService in com.bookstore.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.bookstore.service.impl.UserSecurityService' that could not be found.
        
        The injection point has the following annotations:
            - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    
    
        Action:
        
        Consider defining a bean of type 'com.bookstore.service.impl.UserSecurityService' in your configuration.
```

**UserSecurityService.java**

```
package com.bookstore.service.impl;
        
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
        
import com.bookstore.domain.User;
import com.bookstore.repository.UserRepository;
        
        
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
        
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
                
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
                
                if(null == user) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username Not Found");
                }
                return user;
       }
        
 }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.bookstore.config;
        
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.bookstore.service.impl.UserSecurityService;
import com.bookstore.utility.SecurityUtility;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.bookstore.service.impl.UserSecurityService") 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
    
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
                return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }
            
     private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/image/**",
                "/",
                "/myAccount"
    };
            
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
                http
                        .authorizeRequests().
                        /*antMatchers("/**").*/
                        antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
                        permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
                
                http
                        .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                        .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .rememberMe();
                        
    }
            
    @Autowired 
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
              throws Exception{
              auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            }
             
}
```

Comment: Are you doing what the exception says? Are you requesting a bean in a `destroy()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Service` on your `UserSecurityService` as shown below.

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
            
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
            
            if(null == user) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username Not Found");
            }
            return user;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: @Danny TechDK You can accept this answer so that others will know your issue got resolved